# SOQL Knowledge Search Activity

Tags: soql, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

Can we write SOQL on 'Knowledge Search Activity' ? I know we can create reports with 'Knowledge Search Activity' as report type, but unable to find any leads if we can SOQL on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SearchActivity` object to perform a `SOQL`. Below is the sample query. You can modify the query as per your requirement. .

```
SELECT Id,SearchTerm FROM SearchActivity
```

Refer documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.search_file_activity_report.htm&type=5).

Describe the object in `Developer Console` and check for other fields available as per your need.

Adding a screenshot of available fields for your reference.
[image]